# Linear independence of an odd set of measurable functions

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $g(t)$ be a convex positive function.  I'm trying to show that the set $\{ |t|^ne^{\frac{g(t)}{t^n}}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is linearly independent in the space of measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ (ie: $L^0(\mathbb{R})$).

I tried working in a weighted $L^2_w(\mathbb{R})$ space but these are not orthogonal so I can't use that type of argument.  How could I go about showing this?

In a nutshel I'm trying to show it's a Schauder basis.

Comment: If you were considering functions defined just on the positive half of the real line, then your functions for $n=0$ and for $n=1$ could be linearly dependent; in fact, they could be equal if $g(t)=(t\cdot\ln t)/(t-1)$ (if I did the arithmetic right). This particular example doesn't work for negative $t$, but I wouldn't be surprised if more complicated dependences can occur on all of $\mathbb R$ for some maliciously designed functions $g(t)$.

Comment: That dounction isn't convex though, however I'm most interested in the case where $g(t)$ is constant anyway.

Comment: If g is a constant, then those functions are linearly independent just because each is infinitesimal wrto the next.

Comment: Now that you've added "convex" to the question, a positive answer seems reasonably likely.

Comment: So what would that be then?